# Strange inconsistency when using ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints in pydrake

Tags: drake

I'm using drake to generate a walking gait for a legged robot. To do this, I need a way to determine when it's appropriate to apply contact forces. For this I'm using ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints between the claws (feet) of the robot and a box which I'm using as the floor (world body):

```
# Relevant geometry ids

Worldbody_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('WorldBody')]
FL_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('Link_FL_3')]
FR_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('Link_FR_3')]
ML_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('Link_ML_3')]
MR_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('Link_MR_3')]
BL_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('Link_BL_3')]
BR_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('Link_BR_3')]

Claw_id = [FL_claw_id, FR_claw_id, ML_claw_id, MR_claw_id, BL_claw_id, BR_claw_id]
# Claw_id[0] = FL_claw_id
# Claw_id[1] = FR_claw_id
# Claw_id[2] = ML_claw_id
# Claw_id[3] = MR_claw_id
# Claw_id[4] = BL_claw_id
# Claw_id[5] = BR_claw_id
print(Claw_id)
```

As a test I'm doing the following:

```
Distances = np.zeros(5)
for i in range(6):
    print(Distances)
    Distances[i] = query_object.ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints(Worldbody_id, Claw_id[i]).distance
```

Unfortunately this produces the following error:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[-0.04070674  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-077874ed3da0> in <module>
      2 for i in range(6):
      3     print(Distances)
----> 4     Distances[i] = query_object.ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints(Worldbody_id, Claw_id[i]).distance
      5 
      6 

RuntimeError: The geometry given by id 63 does not reference a geometry that can be used in a signed distance query
```

This implies that the geometry type used by the geometry corresponding to the FR_Claw_id differs from the one corresponding to FL_Claw_id. This is despite the fact that they're both meshes (obj files).

Does anybody know what I'm not seeing?

---

Using a urdf with much simpler geometry (only boxes), this problem persists (this urdf was made by hand, so the intertial data is probably wrong).

Here's the code used:

```
    # Imports required for this programme
import numpy as np
import os

from pydrake.common import FindResourceOrThrow, temp_directory
from pydrake.geometry import (
    MeshcatVisualizerCpp,
    MeshcatVisualizerParams,
    Role,
    StartMeshcat,
)
from pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram import MathematicalProgram
from pydrake.math import RigidTransform, RollPitchYaw
from pydrake.multibody.meshcat import JointSliders
from pydrake.multibody.parsing import Parser
from pydrake.multibody.plant import AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph
from pydrake.multibody.plant import MultibodyPlant
from pydrake.multibody.optimization import StaticEquilibriumProblem
from pydrake.multibody.tree import Joint
from pydrake.systems.analysis import Simulator
from pydrake.systems.framework import DiagramBuilder
from pydrake.all import *

hexapod_file = "/home/remi/catkin_ws/src/hexapod/SCAWeR.urdf"
builder = DiagramBuilder()

# Note: the time_step here is chosen arbitrarily.
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.001)

# Adding a ground plane
normal_W = [0, 0, 1]
point_W = [0, 0, 10]

surface_friction = CoulombFriction(
  0.8 # static friction
 ,0.3)# dynamic friction

# A box for the ground geometry.
plant.RegisterCollisionGeometry(
    plant.world_body(), HalfSpace.MakePose(normal_W, point_W),
    Box(100, 100, 1), "collision", surface_friction)

# Load the file into the plant/scene_graph.
parser = Parser(plant)
parser.package_map().PopulateFromFolder("/home/remi/catkin_ws/src/hexapod")
parser.AddModelFromFile(hexapod_file)
plant.Finalize()

# create context for plant
plant_ad = plant.ToAutoDiffXd()
context_ad = plant_ad.CreateDefaultContext()

# creating an inspector
diagram = builder.Build()
diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
scene_graph_context = scene_graph.GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram_context) 
query_object = scene_graph.get_query_output_port().Eval(scene_graph_context)
inspector = query_object.inspector()

# Compiling a list of the names of the bodies in the world (same order as geometry id list)
body_list = []
for geometry_id in inspector.GetAllGeometryIds():
    body = plant.GetBodyFromFrameId(inspector.GetFrameId(geometry_id))
    body_list.append(body.name())
    
# Relevant geometry ids
Worldbody_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('WorldBody')]
FL_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('leg_l1_3')]
FR_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('leg_r1_3')]
ML_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('leg_l2_3')]
MR_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('leg_r2_3')]
BL_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('leg_l3_3')]
BR_claw_id = inspector.GetAllGeometryIds()[body_list.index('leg_r3_3')]

# Assigning the claw_ids to a list for ease of use
Claw_id = [FL_claw_id, FR_claw_id, ML_claw_id, MR_claw_id, BL_claw_id, BR_claw_id]
# Claw_id[0] = FL_claw_id
# Claw_id[1] = FR_claw_id
# Claw_id[2] = ML_claw_id
# Claw_id[3] = MR_claw_id
# Claw_id[4] = BL_claw_id
# Claw_id[5] = BR_claw_id

# Assigning the relevant geometries for ease of use
Claw_name = ['leg_l1_3', 'leg_r1_3', 'leg_l2_3', 'leg_r2_3', 'leg_l3_3', 'leg_r3_3']

def GetNameFromGeometryID(ID):
    return plant.GetBodyFromFrameId(inspector.GetFrameId(ID)).name()

def SignedDistance(name):
    dList = query_object.ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints()
    idW = Worldbody_id
    for i in range(len(dList)):
        idB = dList[i].id_B
        idA = dList[i].id_A
        if (idW == dList[i].id_A) and (name == GetNameFromGeometryID(idB)):
            distance = dList[i]
            return distance
        elif (idW == dList[i].id_B) and (name == GetNameFromGeometryID(idA)):
            distance = dList[i]
            return distance
```

Thhe custom function defined here, SignedDistance, uses ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints as a proxy to find the distances I need:

```
Distances = np.zeros(6)
for i in range(len(Claw_name)):
    Distances[i] = SignedDistance(Claw_name[i]).distance
    
        
print(Distances)
```

Curiously this works as opposed to using ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints:

```
Distances = np.zeros(6)
for i in range(len(Claw_id)):
    Distances[i] = query_object.ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints(Worldbody_id, Claw_id[i])
    
print(Distances)
```

Here's the urdf I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<robot name="scawer">
    <!-- Defining materials -->
    <material name="mat_body">
        <color rgba="0.1 0.1 0.4 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="mat_link_0">
        <color rgba="0.35 0.4 0.35 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="mat_link_1">
        <color rgba="0.5 0.35 0.35 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="mat_link_2">
        <color rgba="0.35 0.35 0.5 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="mat_link_3">
        <color rgba="0.25 0.25 0.25 1.0"/>
    </material>
    <!-- End Defining materials -->

    <link name="body">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.2 0.1 0.05"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="mat_body"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.2 0.1 0.05"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.8"/>
            <inertia ixx="8.33e-4" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="2.83e-3" iyz="0.0" izz="3.33e-3"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- Leg R1 Begin -->
    <link name="leg_r1_0">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.01 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_0"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.01 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="2.604e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="2.604e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_r1_1">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_1"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_r1_2">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_2"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_r1_3">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.045 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_3"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.045 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="3.46875e-5" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="3.46875e-5"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="r1_j0" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0.1 -0.05 0"/> <!--rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>-->
        <parent link="body"/>
        <child link="leg_r1_0"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
        <limit lower="-1.0471975512" upper="2.09439510239" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="r1_j1" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 -0.02 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_r1_0"/>
        <child link="leg_r1_1"/>
        <axis xyz="1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.09439510239" upper="2.09439510239" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="r1_j2" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 -0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_r1_1"/>
        <child link="leg_r1_2"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 -1.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="r1_j3" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 -0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_r1_2"/>
        <child link="leg_r1_3"/>
        <axis xyz="1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.356" upper="2.356" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    <!-- Leg R1 End -->

    <!-- Leg L1 Begin -->
    <link name="leg_l1_0">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.01 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_0"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.01 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="2.604e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="2.604e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_l1_1">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_1"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_l1_2">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_2"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_l1_3">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.045 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_3"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.045 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="3.46875e-5" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="3.46875e-5"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="l1_j0" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0.1 0.05 0"/> <!-- rpy="3.1416 0.0 0.0"/>-->
        <parent link="body"/>
        <child link="leg_l1_0"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 -1.0"/>
        <limit lower="-1.0471975512" upper="2.09439510239" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="l1_j1" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.02 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_l1_0"/>
        <child link="leg_l1_1"/>
        <axis xyz="-1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.09439510239" upper="2.09439510239" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="l1_j2" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_l1_1"/>
        <child link="leg_l1_2"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 -1.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="l1_j3" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_l1_2"/>
        <child link="leg_l1_3"/>
        <axis xyz="-1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.356" upper="2.356" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    <!-- Leg L1 End -->

    <!-- Leg R2 Begin -->
    <link name="leg_r2_0">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.01 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_0"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.01 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="2.604e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="2.604e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_r2_1">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_1"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_r2_2">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_2"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_r2_3">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.045 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_3"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.045 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="3.46875e-5" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="3.46875e-5"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="r2_j0" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 -0.05 0"/> <!--rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>-->
        <parent link="body"/>
        <child link="leg_r2_0"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
        <limit lower="-1.0471975512" upper="1.047197551" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="r2_j1" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 -0.02 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_r2_0"/>
        <child link="leg_r2_1"/>
        <axis xyz="1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.09439510239" upper="2.09439510239" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="r2_j2" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 -0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_r2_1"/>
        <child link="leg_r2_2"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 -1.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="r2_j3" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 -0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_r2_2"/>
        <child link="leg_r2_3"/>
        <axis xyz="1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.356" upper="2.356" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    <!-- Leg R2 End -->

    <!-- Leg L2 Begin -->
    <link name="leg_l2_0">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.01 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_0"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.01 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="2.604e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="2.604e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_l2_1">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_1"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_l2_2">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_2"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_l2_3">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.045 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_3"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.045 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="3.46875e-5" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="3.46875e-5"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="l2_j0" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.05 0"/> <!-- rpy="3.1416 0.0 0.0"/>-->
        <parent link="body"/>
        <child link="leg_l2_0"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 -1.0"/>
        <limit lower="-1.0471975512" upper="1.047197551" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="l2_j1" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.02 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_l2_0"/>
        <child link="leg_l2_1"/>
        <axis xyz="-1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.09439510239" upper="2.09439510239" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="l2_j2" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_l2_1"/>
        <child link="leg_l2_2"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 -1.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="l2_j3" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_l2_2"/>
        <child link="leg_l2_3"/>
        <axis xyz="-1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.356" upper="2.356" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    <!-- Leg L2 End -->

    <!-- Leg R3 Begin -->
    <link name="leg_r3_0">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.01 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_0"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.01 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="2.604e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="2.604e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_r3_1">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_1"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_r3_2">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_2"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_r3_3">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.045 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_3"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.045 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="3.46875e-5" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="3.46875e-5"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="r3_j0" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="-0.1 -0.05 0"/> <!--rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>-->
        <parent link="body"/>
        <child link="leg_r3_0"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.09439510239" upper="1.0471975512" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="r3_j1" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 -0.02 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_r3_0"/>
        <child link="leg_r3_1"/>
        <axis xyz="1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.09439510239" upper="2.09439510239" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="r3_j2" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 -0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_r3_1"/>
        <child link="leg_r3_2"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 -1.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="r3_j3" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 -0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_r3_2"/>
        <child link="leg_r3_3"/>
        <axis xyz="1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.356" upper="2.356" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    <!-- Leg R3 End -->

    <!-- Leg L3 Begin -->
    <link name="leg_l3_0">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.01 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_0"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.02 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.01 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="2.604e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="2.604e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_l3_1">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_1"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_l3_2">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_2"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0225 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="9.375e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="9.375e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="leg_l3_3">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.045 0.0"/>
            <material name="mat_link_3"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.015 0.09 0.015"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.045 0.0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.05"/>
            <inertia ixx="3.46875e-5" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.875e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="3.46875e-5"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="l3_j0" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="-0.1 0.05 0"/> <!-- rpy="3.1416 0.0 0.0"/>-->
        <parent link="body"/>
        <child link="leg_l3_0"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 -1.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.09439510239" upper="1.0471975512" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="l3_j1" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.02 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_l3_0"/>
        <child link="leg_l3_1"/>
        <axis xyz="-1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.09439510239" upper="2.09439510239" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="l3_j2" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_l3_1"/>
        <child link="leg_l3_2"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 -1.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="l3_j3" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.045 0"/> <!-- rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> -->
        <parent link="leg_l3_2"/>
        <child link="leg_l3_3"/>
        <axis xyz="-1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <limit lower="-2.356" upper="2.356" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
    <!-- Leg L3 1End -->
</robot>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the *collision* geometry is an obj in both cases?  Just a guess, but maybe you have some simpler collision geometry on FR/FL that is missing on ML?

Comment: The collision geometry and visual geometry are exactly the same file. Checking the visual and collision model in meshcat confirms this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited)

There were several issues as things evolved. It's worth keeping not of each of them as each served as a stumbling block to simply finding out distances between bodies.

- The original issue: using a mesh that isn't supported by the query function
  [ComputeSignedDistancePairClosest](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_query_object.html#a7a66a8b3fc43f34d11a9cd475fb77ee1), box-mesh isn't supported for that query.

  - Easily resolved by swapping half space for box (for the ground).
- The new issue (in the code posted 8/28/2022) is that you were grabbing ids for *all* geometries.

  - In your urdf your bodies are defined with both `<collision>` and `<visual>` tags. That means you have two (or more) geometries associated with each body. But not all of them can be used for distance queries -- which is what you ran into. You asked a distance query about a geometry that had, for example, an illustration role.
  - Below, I've provided a code snippet to how it might be more properly done. The coding style is a mix of yours and mine. Sorry 'bout that.

```py
...
# creating an inspector
diagram = builder.Build()

query_object = scene_graph.get_query_output_port().Eval(scene_graph_context)
inspector = query_object.inspector()

# The names of the bodies we care about -- we'll test their distance to the
# ground box.
Claw_name = ['leg_l1_3', 'leg_r1_3', 'leg_l2_3', 'leg_r2_3', 'leg_l3_3',
             'leg_r3_3']
body_geometries = {}
for body_name in Claw_name:
    f_id = plant.GetBodyFrameIdOrThrow(plant.GetBodyByName(body_name).index())
    # For distance queries, only get geometries with the proximity role.
    body_geometries[body_name] = inspector.GetGeometries(f_id, Role.kProximity)

# Get the GeometryId for the ground box.
world_ids = inspector.GetGeometries(scene_graph.world_frame_id(),
                                    Role.kProximity)
assert(len(world_ids) == 1)
Worldbody_id = world_ids[0]

assert(len(body_geometries) == 6)
Distances = np.zeros(6)
i = 0
for body_name in Claw_name:
    g_ids = body_geometries[body_name]
    assert(len(g_ids) == 1)
    Distances[i] = query_object.ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints(
        Worldbody_id, g_ids[0]).distance
    i += 1
print(Distances)
```

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that ComputeSignedDistancePairClosest doesn't support non-convex meshes. I'll create a simpler collision model in my own time, thank you.

It's still a bit strange how the front left claw of the model, despite being visually identical to the other claws, works with ComputeSignedDistancePairClosest anyways.

Is there a way to check whether drake recognizes the geometry as convex?

Comment: Drake makes no assumptions about convexity. It has to be told explicitly something is convex (either by declaring a shape it knows to be convex or using the `<drake:declare_convex>` tag). But that assertion isn't checked. If you say it's convex, we treat it as convex. And if it isn't, then there is undefined behavior.

Comment: I recreated the model with much simpler geometry (all boxes), and am experiencing the same problem; some boxes are parsed by ComputeSignedDistancePairClosest, while others give an error stating that the geometry is not supported by the query, despite the fact that the geometries are exactly the same.

Comment: What you're describing is inexplicable. There are two possibilities: there is an absolutely inexplicable bug that has somehow been missed, or, your geometry isn't quite what you think it is. Can you confirm that all the geometries are boxes? Let me know if you need some help in doing that.

Comment: The geometries are all defined as boxes in the urdf, does this not translate to drake?

Comment: Small update: I tried finding the distances through ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints instead, and it works perfectly. As far as I can tell from the documentation, ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints has the same restrictions as the aforementioned function. What could cause this inconsistency?

Comment: Update 2: When comparing the results of the two functions we're finding strange geometry id mismatches

Comment: I think we've hit the point where reproducibility is key. Do you have an example (as simple as possible) that you can make available to me?

Comment: I've added the segment of code and the urdf which produce this inconsistency to the question.

Comment: The code you've added was sufficient for me to figure out your last problem. I've updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: BTW I've submitted a PR to better help people recognize when they've fallen in this trap. https://github.com/robotlocomotion/drake/pull/17826